# Intellij - Change Default Class Path For TestNG Run Configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

Is there any way I can have IntelliJ default my module chasspath to not the main one? I'm currently doing this manually for every test I'm trying to run to avoid getting a `cannot find class in classpath` error. I would like to have `org.apache.maven.sl` as the default instead of `main`

[image]

This is my default template

[image]

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could change template for this configuration. Open "Run | Edit Configuration", find "TestNG" under templates and select needed classpath from dropdown list.

Comment: Hi @y.bedrov, thanks for your answer. I actually had this there already (updated the question now) but for some reason it seems to make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Finally what worked for me was updating and reinstalling IntelliJ.